# Javascript: Get Name of Current Object Property in Object Literal

Tags: javascript

File this one under "just curious" or "is it possible?"

Say for example I have...

```
home: function(options) {
   this._home('home', options)
}

login: function(options) {
    this._home('login', options)
}
```

`home` and `login` are obviously identifiers on dozens of object properties for tracking purposes. Is there a way to just return `home` or `login` without using any variables (an external function call is fine) within the object property?

**UPDATE:** Turns out this isn't possible. The accepted answer doesn't exactly answer the question, but it is a wonderful example of simplifying numerous calls to the same property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean that within the function that the `home` property references you want to be able to somehow get the string `"home"` from that property name without hardcoding it then no, to the best of my knowledge that isn't possible.

Just guessing at what you're trying to achieve, would something like this help at least a little bit:

```
function callHome(propName) {
   return function(options) {
      this._home(propName, options);
   }
}

var someObj = {
   home: callHome('home'),
   login: callHome('login')
}
someObj.home({some:"option"});
```

At least then you don't have to repeat the same function body for each property. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/EeEAw/

**Note:** I assume that the `_home()` function invoked but not defined in the question would be defined somewhere in the real-world code. I don't show it in my answer, though I created a dummy one in my fiddle.

Just as an aside, note that the function doesn't really "belong" to the object or to the property - there's nothing stopping you doing this sort of thing:

```
var obj = {
   test : "test",
   home : function() {
      alert(this.test);
   }
};
var funcRef = obj.home;
var obj2 = {
   method1 : funcRef
}
obj.home = null;
funcRef();
obj2.method1();
```

That is, you can create multiple references to the same function, and the function will continue to exist even if the original `obj.home` property is set to some other value (as long as the additional references continue to exist).

Comment: Ooops, you can't dynamically set object properties like that. `home: callHome('home')` throws a typeError (attempting to call something that isn't a function) because there is no `_home` property.

Comment: @RobG - I assumed the OP would provide the `_home` property since it wasn't shown in the question, but in my jsfiddle demo I did provide a sample `_home`. Having said that, in fact you _don't_ get an error when creating the object - there's no problem with `home:callHome('home')` within the object literal because `callHome()` doesn't use the missing `_home` property, it returns another function that uses `_home`. You only get a problem later if you try to say `someObj.home()` and at that point there is still no `_home` function.

Comment: @RobG - I'm not sure if your last comment is referring to calling `callHome()` or `home()` - I'll assume the latter because that means you agree with me. Either way, I've added a note to the answer to indicate that `_home()` needs to be defined.

Comment: @nnnnnn Thanks for a detailed answer. `_home` is defined as another property. We're using Backbone so that's the reason it's setup like this. Your first sentence: "If you mean that within the function that the home property references you want to be able to somehow get the string "home" from that property name without hardcoding it then no, to the best of my knowledge that isn't possible." - that's exactly what I was after. That being said, your answer is a wonderful help to others and I'll accept it with an update in the question. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Identifier resolution and object property look up use completely separate methods. You can use *with* to add an object to the top of the scope chain, but it is very much recommended against and may well fail completely in strict mode.

So if you have:

```
var obj = {test:'test'};
alert(test);
```

then the identifier *test* is resolved on the scope chain. Since it doesn't exist there, an error is thrown. However, for:

```
alert(obj.test);
```

then firstly *obj* is resolved and found as a reference to an object, then the identifier *test* is resolved as a property of the object. You can also use *with*:

```
with (obj) {
  alert(test);
}
```

in which case *obj* is temporarily placed at the top of the scope chain and so *test* is resolved on it first.